# How to stop embedded HTML files from downloading?

Tags: html, file, iframe

I have a .html document that I need in an `<iframe>` tag. Let's say it is called `FILE.html` and is hosted at `http://files.net/FILE.html`.

So, I write the iframe tag as such:
`<iframe src="http://files.net/FILE.html"></iframe>`

Instead of the iframe appearing as a nice little box and rendering the html in `FILE.html`, it instead opens File Explorer and prompts the user to download `FILE.html`. I don't want them to download it, I just want them to see it rendered on their screen.

So is there a way for me to format it such that the html renders and doesn't download? Can I change the `FILE.html`, or change the iframe tag, or upload it in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something about the way that file is being served is telling the browser that it isn't an HTML file that can be displayed. This is probably because its Content-Type header is incorrect, but may also be because the file is being served with a Content-Disposition header that instructs the browser to download it.

Assuming that you have access to the server that this file is being served from, you will need to configure it to use the correct headers. There is no way to override these headers in a frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - could you possibly tell me what headers I should be using?

Comment: first thing first,  get the headers in the network trace and see whats headers are in response.

Comment: also check the mime type

Comment: @snazzybouche The Content-Type should be set to `text/html` (or `text/html;charset=UTF-8`, etc), and Content-Disposition should not be set.

Comment: The header of the file is `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>`

I don't know how to check the MIME type, but I'll change the content-type to what duskwuff suggested

Comment: @snazzybouche That looks like the beginning of the file, not the HTTP headers…

Comment: Yes - if that's not what you need, I'm not sure what you're asking for - could I possibly have further instruction? EDIT: I have access to the file but not to the server - I guess I'll find another upload site that has the right headers