# Reactjs: load Iframe URl in the same domain fails in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a GET service which returns some html and I need to set this as a URL in an Iframe.
The service is being hosted in the same path `{domain}/service`
but the problem is that **it is being considered as a react route** and fails there.

Is there any way to avoid this?

```
 <iframe
   src={url}
 />
```

Comment: Ideally only response with text/html mime-type should be rendered inside iframe instead of being considered as a file or a link to follow.
Can you post the raw result of the request from GET endpoint using curl or from devtools in browser ?

Comment: its a simple html file |
eg: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <body>
............................
  </body>
</html>
`
@AntoineRaoulIscaros

Comment: That's just the body of the request, please provide the headers.

Comment: `<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/**/btc/btc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/**/btc/bridgeJS.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/**/btc/jquery_signalr.js"></script>
</head>`
@AntoineRaoulIscaros i hope this is what you asked

Comment: can you please get me the request headers, not html head.
for example use ```curl -I -X GET {your-endpoint}```

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445215/how-to-stop-embedded-html-files-from-downloading?rq=1